# Algorithm to balance output of quadatric functions, yield optimization

Tags: optimization, quadratics, linear-regression

I apologize in advance, I don't come from a mathematics background.  I'm trying to understand if there are any known algorithm for the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm not a student, I'm just trying to learn.

I'll try to describe what's going on in an anecdote:

Lets say there are a bunch of stores earn fix daily profits.
Each one of these stores makes a different amount of profit
I can buy a percentage of that company to earn a dividend of their rewards
Everyday other people come and buy shares changing the amount of dividends I'm earning so I need to adjust.

In more mathematically terms:

I have a list of quadratic functions whose inputs are dependent on the results from the previous function.  I'm looking for an algorithm to return the highest output in a while at most iterating over the functions n log n times.

I feel like this has something to do with linear regression, are there any simple algorithms which can handle this?

Comment: This is more in the realm of consulting rather than the specific help that you might find here.

Comment: I'm not really looking for the solution, I'm mostly looking into finding out how to categorize these problems so I can better research the solution

Comment: There is not enough detail above to be able to guess what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @copper.hat to simplify, I'm trying to figure out daily which stock provides the best dividends based on how much I supply